# Rendering a particle effect with additive blending

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to render particles with an additive blending effect and it's work good when the background is black

[image]

but if the background is white i got this and i understand why (color particle + white => white)

[image]

my pseudo code is

```
renderOtherObjects();
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
renderParticles();
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

so my question is, is it possible to ignore the other elements for additive blending without using the "render to a texture" method ?

Edit 1:

If i try glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE); instead of glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);

[image]

Edit 2:

I want this result:

[image]

Comment: Try `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);` instead of `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);`

Comment: Not working with glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE); i edited the question

Comment: How do you WANT it to look? (an image here would be the best.) You basically cannot see emissive phenomena over white background. E.g. can't see flames in bright sunlight very well (there's smoke and our eyes don't saturate IRL so can still see something).

Comment: I want to have the result of the first image regardless of the background. i want only a additive blending between particles and not with other elements.

Comment: In other words, you don't want to blend with the background. Not possible without some kind of intermediate buffer in place. Easiest to render to a texture/separate frame buffer with blending enabled, then copy that onto the main image.

Comment: @Hugh Fisher yep i don't want to blend with the background. The problem is if i use another buffer, I would no longer have a depth test between particles and other elements.

Comment: If they're pixel size particles, maybe not bother blending at all? If they're moving around, people won't have time to study individual frames and notice tiny discrepencies. Or if you're willing to accept some slowdown, offset each particles Z coord by a small amount based on brightness, so brighter particles end up on top.